# How should I create a folder that automatically links to a shared drive between Windows and Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, folder-redirection

I'd like to set it up so that when I click on my 'My Pictures|Videos|Music...etc' folder it just redirects to my middle data drive. Likewise for my linux folders.

How can I set this up? I'm sorry if this is quite vague, I'm not really sure what is possible at all so please help me out.

Comment: Is this for a dual-boot setup, or is one of the OSes running in a virtual machine?

Comment: Also, what does "middle data drive" refer to in this case?

Comment: @AndersonGreen To clarify I have three partitions on a dual boot using ext2fsd. My 'middle data driver's is an ext3 partition just for data, with programs and OSes on the other partitions

Comment: Should this middle data partition remains ext2fs-formatted?

Comment: @Serge if possible, I don't want to have to reformat it.

Comment: Then I see that you have only one option. Though I am sure you would not like it: Install VM, onto VM - linux, then share with Samba )). It's a joke, it's not an advise)

Comment: @Serge I don't get it... ext2fsd lets windows read/write ext2 and ext3 file systems

Comment: really? I thought this is a typo. I didn't heared about ext2fsd. let me get some info.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Samba On Ubuntu**

First Goto the Terminal      Applications>Accessories>Terminal

Inside the Terminal type :    sudo apt-get install samba smbfs

When asked for the Password, please type in your administrator password!

After the Installation Finishes, Close the Terminal

[image: Picture 1]

**Configuring Samba (Using Samba Front End)**

In order to configure Samba, as specify users and folders to share, I found it so much easy to use the “Samba” GUI.

So Lets Install Samba (GUI) First!

Goto Applications > Add / Remove Applications

Search For “Samba”

Tick The program Named “Samba” which has the description “Create, Modify, and delete samba shares”

Click Apply Changes

[image: Picture 2]

After Installation is Finished, lets start the Samba GUI!

Goto   System > Administration> Samba

Provide the correct administrator password to start the application.

**Configuring Users**

First in the Samba GUI Goto Preferences> Samba Users

There You will see the existing users in your Linux OS,

you can create a user specifically to be used to access ones shared in the Linux Computer,

To Do this just Click  “Add User” and then provide the Necessary data such as User name and Password for the New User.

After Everything is Done Click OK

**Configuring Shares**

Click “Add Share”

Specify the Directory or Partition You Want to Share,

Provide a Suitable Share Name

Description

Tick the “Visible” Radio Button

If you want, Tick the “Writable” button as Well.

Goto the “Access” tab

Tick the Users You want to Give access to this Share,

Or If you want to make in a public share for every one to use, just Tick “Allow Access To Everyone“.

Click OK.

[image: Picture 3]

Comment: Good guide! What does it do though?

Comment: I thought you want to share a drive or some folders between Windows and Linux. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes i do...but you haven't explained how your method achieves this.

Comment: According to my explanation you can access to a shared folder in Linux from Windows. Therefore you have access to this shared folder from both Windows and Linux.

Comment: But..you've explained the process, but not what samba share does. That least sentence alone says more about the *what* than the *why* of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This `Ext2fsd` [FAQ](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=7) states:

> Q) What's a permanent mountpoint ?
>
> A) Windows system's mount manager will automatically mount volumes and
>   assign driver letters during booting. For xp and later systems,
>   windows    only create unique volume ids for all the recognized
>   volume/partitions,    such as FAT32, NTFS. **The ext2/ext3 volumes could
>   not be mounted by the    windows mount manager**.
>
> Ext2Mgr provides 3 methods to mount a Linux volume:
>
> 1, Using Windows API DefineDosDevice
>         Driver letter won't be kept and be lost after reboot. But it's convenient
>         for a temporary usage.
>
> 2, Using Windows MountMgr + Ext2Mgr
>         This method provides automatic mounting when Ext2Mgr detects new
>         disk is plugged and removal of driver letters after disk is removed.
>         If you are heavily using removable disks, this is the best choice.
>
> 3, Using registry to store the driver letter as a DosDevice
>         This method always works and it's better for fixed harddisks. Under
>         some conditions, you need a reboot to see the driver letter in explorer.
>
> ```
>   You could also modify the registry manually, see below:
>
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
>   "X:"="\\Device\\HarddiskVolume1"
> ```

This means that the only available options to mount ext2 formatted volumes with it is with drive letter. So, one can not mount ext2 volume as a folder. However it is possible to mount the volume at `boot time`.

Thus probably the easiest way to solve your problem is to make a shortcuts to appropriate directories in your Windows `Documents` folder.

With linux you can add permanent `bind` mounts in `fstab`, for example:

```
/path_toyour_mddm_ount_point/Videos /path_to_you_home/Documents/Vdideo none bind
```

Comment: I don't have an issue mounting the drive in windows....I think I understand wat you're saying about fstab, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @Pureferret do you need clarification?