# How can add a samba share as a drive under Win7?

Tags: windows-7, mount, samba

I would like to store the PC Home folder on a server using Samba. I found some [information](http://robpaller.com/archive/2009/05/relocating-the-users-folder-in-windows-7/), how can I move the Home folder. I would like to move this folder to a Samba share, on Linux there is the fstab to mount share folder. How can I mount under win 7 this shared folder as a partition, during the system start, using username and passwords?

Comment: Use this link for configure the Samba http://superuser.com/a/481827/145058

Comment: My question is not related to the samba configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
mklink /d C:\userhomes \\server\share
```

That doesn't actually mount the share but creates a symbolic link to it. Every user permitted to access the share can transparently access it through the symlink. You grant access by setting appropriate permissions on the Samba share.

Comment: How can I start the network, and how can I mount the samba  before login? How can I grant access to this drive for everybody?

Comment: See updated answer.